# How to add border to text box (image box ) converted using imagettftext() function

Tags: javascript, php, css, imagettftext

Here i am trying to add border to image which is converted from user input text to image using
imagettftext() function.Any body have any idea how will i achieve that.

Demo Link:- [Click Here](http://stencils.bluecoresyspvtltd.com/stencil%20with%20select%20box/custom%20stencil/)

Looking for expected output like bellow snap shot

[image: expected output]

Bellow is sample php code which i am using to convert text to image.

```
<?php session_start();
  header("Content-type: image/png");
$myArray = explode(',', $_GET['img']);  
$fontarray = explode(',' , $_GET['fontsize']);   
$align =$_GET['align'];


####################### BEGIN USER EDITS #######################   
$imagewidth = 1000;
$imageheight = 1000;
$fontangle = "0";
$font = "Outlinesten_6.ttf";
$backgroundcolor = "FFFFFF";
$textcolor = "#000000";

### Convert HTML backgound color to RGB
if( @eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $backgroundcolor, $bgrgb ) )
{$bgred = hexdec( $bgrgb[1] );   $bggreen = hexdec( $bgrgb[2] );   $bgblue = hexdec( $bgrgb[3] );}

### Convert HTML text color to RGB
if( @eregi( "([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})", $textcolor, $textrgb ) )
{$textred = hexdec( $textrgb[1] );   $textgreen = hexdec( $textrgb[2] );   $textblue = hexdec( $textrgb[3] );}

### Create image
$im = imagecreate( $imagewidth, $imageheight );

### Declare image's background color
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgred,$bggreen,$bgblue);

### Declare image's text color
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textred,$textgreen,$textblue);
  if($align=='center'  )
         {
### Get exact dimensions of text string

       $ycord=0;

//$ycord = ($imageheight/2)-($textheight/2)*2 ; 
       $testcount=0;
### Declare completed image with colors, font, text, and text location      
$count=count($myArray); 
       $totalprice=0;
$testnewcount=0;
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
        $newcount=count($fontarray); 

        for($j=0;$j<$newcount;$j++)

{


    if($j==$i)
    {



            //$box = imageTTFBbox(50,$fontangle,$font,'test');  
       $box = imageTTFBbox($fontarray[$j],$fontangle,$font,$myArray[$i]);    

### Get width of text from dimensions
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);      

### Get height of text from dimensions
$textheight = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);

### Get x-coordinate of centered text horizontally using length of the image and length of the text
//$xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;


        $price= GetPrice($fontarray[$j],$myArray[$i]);


        // $stringnewstr='';
     //   $string=$myArray[$i];

$totalprice=$totalprice+$price;
### Get y-coordinate of centered text vertically using height of the image and height of the text
//$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2); 

        // if($align=='center')
        // {
           $xcord = ($imagewidth/2)-($textwidth/2)-2;   

       // $ycord =(( ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2))  )+$testcount; 
        // $testcount=$testcount+65;  
        if($i==0)
        {
             $testnewcount= $fontarray[$j];      
        }
              //$testcount=$testcount+$fontarray[$j]/2;    
            if($testnewcount<$fontarray[$j])
            {
                  $testcount=$testcount+$fontarray[$j]/2;

                  $ycord =(( ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2))  )+$testcount;  

            }
            else
            {
                $ycord =(( ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2))  )+$testcount;  


            }

         $testcount=$testcount+$fontarray[$j]; 

         $testnewcount= $fontarray[$j];     
//$ycord = ($imageheight/2)+($textheight/2);
/*
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
        $newcount=count($fontarray); 

        for($j=0;$j<$newcount;$j++)

{

    if($j==$i)
    {     */
   //  $xcord=$xcord+2;
 //  $ycord=$ycord+100;
  // imagettftext ( $im, $fontarray[$j], $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $myArray[$i] );       
    //    imagettftext ( $im, $fontarray[$j], $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $ycord );   

    imagettftext ( $im, $fontarray[$j], $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $myArray[$i] );   
         }

         }

 } 
   //imagettftext ( $im, 50, $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $fontcolor, $font, $totalprice );  
   $totalprice; 

}
$_SESSION['finalprice']=$totalprice;


$html=imagepng($im);
    //$test="saas";
### Close the image
imagedestroy($im);   

?>
```

Comment: i think you try this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilltoborder.php

Comment: Its adding a border to text i am looking for add to border text box only

Comment: but if you make a image with 2 or 4 pixel margin from text then it can make a border around the textbox